# Display contents of an Wordpress page in an remote iframe

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display the content of a wordpress page in an Iframe on a remote page, but i would like to strip away the logo and menus.... 
This is because I have an public company site with a contact list that is managed by personnel department. I also have an intranet site where I would like to display the same contact list without having to update in to places.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

ON the elements you don't want on the intranet view wrap a conditional block around them. So for example I want to hide my logo and menus as you said, and my logo was in its own div and my menus were ul's I would wrap the #logo div like so:

And the menu ul the same:

```
<?php if (!isset($_GET['iframe'])) {
?><ul id="menu"></ul><?php } ?>
```

To be clear, you are not gonna simply paste any of the above anywhere in your theme files, you will need to look for the elements you want to hide and wrap them with the conditional `<?php if (!isset($_GET['iframe'])) { ?>` which will make them hidden when the page is displayed through your iframe called like so:

```
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com/pageslug/?iframe=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: So i put the firs snip in the header.php on top?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom page template so you have full control over the content. IME, that's easier than conditional statements which may impact the live site as well. I've done this for events so they can put a screen up on a projector and have that info updated live while the site gets updated.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Comment: Custom page templates will not do what the user is asking, because you can only choose one template per page/post. He wants to display the same content in a different way in two places.

Comment: Not sure why you say that, I've done it that way before. There's a lot of ways to do it with a custom page template. It's even possible to use your method with a custom page template. I'm surprised how you don't see how even your method could be used with a custom page template. The advantage of using a custom page template rather than just modifying the core theme files is that if the theme is updated, changes to the core theme file will be erased.